# python & sql server

Tags: python, sql-server

When I do a select  statement for varbinary field in microsoft enterprise manager i get the field on readabel hex format like ab2c2f2d... but when i do the same statment with pymssql i get a gibrish

the select statment is : select x from table --where x the varbinary field

could someone help with this issue ?

Comment: You are not getting "a gibrish", you are getting the raw binary data.

Comment: But how i can convert it to hex format like what shown in microsoft enterprise manager

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Enterprise Manager is converting the binary value to a hexadecimal string for you.

One option is to change your query to SELECT CAST( x AS varchar ) FROM table.  This will have SQL Server convert the varbinary to a hexdecimal string for you, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx

Another option is to use the python module, [binascii](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#module-binascii) to convert the binary data to a hexadecimal string yourself.  You use the functions binascii.b2a_hex(data) or binascii.hexlify(data) to do this.